# Android - <merge /> tag conflict with RelativeLayout root

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to position three included layouts in a RelativeLayout. 
In each included layout I'm using the `tools:showIn` option since the root of the layouts is a `<merge />`. 
The problem is that the included layouts tags are **overlapping**, as if the `layout_below` where totally ignored:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        layout="@layout/collab_header_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="90dp" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/body"
        layout="@layout/collab_body_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="225dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/header" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        layout="@layout/collab_footer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/body" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried to include another layout in wich the root tag is not `<merge />` and I can position it in the Relative Layout without problems. 
What should I do ? 
**Thx** anticipately !

Comment: try using +id/{id} on layout_below or better use LinearLayout with vertical orientation

Answer (score 0):

All the positions need to be declared inside the merged layout. 
i.e:

```
<-- Root Layout -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include android:id="@+id/tab1"
        layout="@layout/tab_1"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        layout="@layout/collab_header_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="90dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

```
<-- Merged layout -->
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:showIn="@layout/collab_layout">


<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Header"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab1"/>
</merge>
```